# Sound pool volume level

Tags: android, soundpool

Because i had some problem playing small .wav file with MediaPlayer i switched to SoundPool. So far it seems it performing better than MediaPlayer but the problem i am having is the sound level, which should be 0.5 of system sound level.

i tried with

```
soundPool.play(currentSoundId, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1, 0, 1);
```

and it was still at the same sound level, i also tried with

```
int streamId = soundPool.play(currentSoundId, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);
soundPool.setVolume(streamId, 0.5f, 0.5f);
```

and it was same level, any idea how to force to play it at specific volume? Its weird because it seems its not accepting any floats for sound i put in.

EDIT:

i initialize with following constructor

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){

            audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                    .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
                    .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_GAME)
                    .build();

            soundPool = new SoundPool.Builder()
                    .setAudioAttributes(audioAttributes)
                    .setMaxStreams(2)
                    .build();
        }else{
            soundPool = new SoundPool(2, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,0);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should start using ExoPlayer, it has more rigid API then `MediaPlayer` and `SoundPool`
You can find it here, [ExoPlayer](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/exoplayer).

It has `setVolume(float)` api
See more [here](http://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/doc/reference/)

Comment: ExoPlayer is too much for what i need, because i only need to trigger sound when clicking on button.

Answer (score -1):

Is you are using old SoundPool constructor with AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC stream or more relevant SoundPool.Builder ? 
If Builder using, what AudioAttributes passed into initialization ?

Comment: Which Android model and Android version using for testing ?

Comment: This does not answer the question.